# CSS3 image with round corners and a very light oval shape

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Hello I'm looking to build in CSS3 an image with round corners and a very light oval shape, like in this pic.

Not sure if it's possible and how. I know how to build a round image or an image with round corners, but this is a little different.

**UPDATE**
Here is what I've done

```
.round{
    background-color:red;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-top-left-radius: 45px 40px;
    border-top-right-radius: 45px 40px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 45px 40px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 45px 40px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7t1z3hxf/9/

**UPDATE2**
Here are the schematics of what I'm trying to achieve
[image]

[image]

Thanks

Comment: what have you tried? What's the extent of your current knowledge on rounded borders and such? I won't be the one closing it, but if you don't explain that you've at least done a minimal amount of research effort, this question WILL end up being closed, I can almost guarantee you

Comment: @Markasoftware I've updated the post. My problem is with the top and bottom , because I want them to be oval, and the left and right to be more straight

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If perfect precision is what you want, I recommend `mask-image` instead of `border-radius`. It's much better suited for what you want.

To use your Illustrator-built(?) shape as a `mask` in CSS, export it as SVG or PNG with transparent bg.

This will work in Chrome, Safari and Opera, but you need to use the prefixed `-webkit-mask-image`. The property is in progress of being merged with CSS `mask-image` which only applied to  SVG, hence the current need for a prefix. For other browsers, you may choose the lesser precise `border-radius`.

```
.round{
 -webkit-mask-image: url(yourshape.png);
 -webkit-mask-size: contain;
 -webkit-mask-position: center center;
 /* ... border-radius as fallback */
}
```

[Learn more about CSS Masking](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/) and browser support.

Answer (score 4):

Adapted from [Here](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)

If it's note exactly what you are looking for, I can mess with the border radii and round it or flatten it.

```css
#round {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  background: orange;
  border-radius: 48% / 25%;
  color: white;
}
#round:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  bottom: 11%;
  right: -5%;
  left: -5%;
  background: inherit;
  border-radius: 21% / 68%;
}
```

```html
<div id="round"></div>
```

Comment: I think that's the technique. It's similar to what I'm looking for, but not exactly. In my example the corners are a little more round and the I think the width is 110px(100px+ 2*5%) instead of 100px. I'm looking for something that can fit in a 100px square box.

Comment: Also can you explain how did you set the round values, from a mathematical point of view

Comment: Well you'll notice that this shape is composed of two separately rounded rectangles. The notation for border-radius is explained [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right you want something like this.

HTML:

```
<DIV CLASS="TEST"></DIV>
```

CSS:

```
.TEST{
   width:230px;
   height:240px;
   background-image:url(IMAGE.JPG);
   border-radius:100px;
   background-position:center center;
   background-size::230px 240px;
 }
```

You may change the values to get the desired position.

Comment: close, but not exactly what I'm looking for. I've updated the main post with the schematics.

Comment: Then,you will need css before & after to achieve this.I could do it but it's a little tricky.Something like those examples : http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/