# How to create this shape using CSS?

Tags: css

I need to create this shape:

[image]

This can't be achieved using `border-radius` (as far I know).

**Obs:** This isn't a oval shape, as discussed in this SO question: [How to give a div oval shape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972145/how-to-give-a-div-oval-shape)

Comment: Why can't you use border-radius?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz He can, it just won't produce the desired result.

Comment: @Harry Yes, it's a dupe.

Comment: mb not. how to create this shape differently? )

Comment: @Harry I see that now :)

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer is - "You cant. But, there are ways to do it."

You could try to use a tool like Mozilla Borders generator, which will output an advanced version of border radius syntax that is supported in all major browsers. : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Border-radius_generator

OR

http://www.css3generator.in/border-radius.html

If it is not pretty enough, you might want to use Clip-Path in conjuction with background-color. More information about that can be found [here](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/) But i want to remind you that unfortunately it is not supported in all browsers. With clip path, you can even draw a SVG and use it as a mask.

I have found out that mask can be used also, so you could check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26246629/css3-image-with-round-corners-and-a-very-light-oval-shape)

Third option would be to use background image...