# How to apply this shape to a image using clip-path?

Tags: css, svg

I already asked a similiar question here: [How to create this shape using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38640277/how-to-create-this-shape-using-css). But is this solution creates a element with background.

Now I need to apply this shape to a image:

[image]

Example:

[image]

**important**: The image will overlap another element, so it **should be transparent** out of its bounds. The example above has a grey background.

I guess the solution is use [`clip-path`](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/). That's what I'm trying: http://jsfiddle.net/gf9uj98j/1/

Comment: Create the shape using inkscape or some other SVG editor.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this solution:

```css
.bg {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
}

#img-test {
  clip-path: url(#clipping);
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipping);
}
```

```html
<div class='bg'>
  <img id="img-test" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjCCj.png">
</div>
      
<svg>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clipping" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <circle cx=".5" cy=".5" r=".4" />
      <ellipse cx=".17" cy=".5" rx=".1" ry=".37" />;
      <ellipse cx=".83" cy=".5" rx=".1" ry=".37" />;
      
      <ellipse cx=".5" cy=".17" rx=".37" ry=".1" />;
      <ellipse cx=".5" cy=".83" rx=".37" ry=".1" />;
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using CSS, just use SVG:

```
<image xlink:href='thesoul2.jpg' y="0" x="200" width="35%" height="40%" 
clip-path="url(#CP)"/>
```

from https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#clipPath